# Highcharts: incorrect column placement with linked series?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to set up column chart with variable column widths. Having different column widths in a single series doesn't seem to be possible, so I've set up multiple series for each required width, and linked them.

But I've run into a problem, illustrated in the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/215tnLna/15/

I've set up the data so that there shouldn't be any gaps... and yet there are gaps in the above jsfiddle. Hover over each column to see the time for that column... the right-hand edge of the column should be placed at that time on the x axis (since pointPlacement is set to -0.5).

BUT the only column series that is aligned correctly, with right-hand edge at the indicated time, is the final one (with a 6 hour span). The first two are shifted left.

What am I doing wrong? Why is this happening, and how do I set this up so that all columns in the linked series are displayed at the correct position?

Thanks.

jsfiddle code:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    title: {
        text: 'Variable width columns'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickInterval: 36e5,
        labels: {
            format: '{value:%H}'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            groupPadding: 0,
            pointPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            grouping: false,
            pointPlacement: -0.5
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: '1hr span',
        type: 'column',
        data: [{"x":1428048000000,"y":8.4},{"x":1428051600000,"y":9},{"x":1428055200000,"y":8.1},{"x":1428058800000,"y":6.6},{"x":1428062400000,"y":5}],
        color: '#22CC00',
        pointRange: 36e5
    },{
        name: '3hr span',
        type: 'column',
        data: [{"x":1428073200000,"y":4.9},{"x":1428084000000,"y":4},{"x":1428094800000,"y":3.4},{"x":1428105600000,"y":2.4}],
        color: '#22CC00',
        linkedTo: ':previous',
        pointRange: 3 * 36e5
    },{
        name: '6hr span',
        type: 'column',
        data: [{"x":1428127200000,"y":6.9}],
        color: '#22CC00',
        linkedTo: ':previous',
        pointRange: 6 * 36e5
    }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set `pointPlacement` value according to span you want to achieve, in your case: http://jsfiddle.net/215tnLna/21/

So if highest span will have `pointPlacement: x`, then series with lower value for the `pointRange` should have decreased `pointPlacement` too. In your case:

```
    series: [{
        name: '1hr span',
        type: 'column',
        data: [{
            "x": 1428048000000,
            "y": 8.4
        }, {
            "x": 1428051600000,
            "y": 9
        }, {
            "x": 1428055200000,
            "y": 8.1
        }, {
            "x": 1428058800000,
            "y": 6.6
        }, {
            "x": 1428062400000,
            "y": 5
        }],
        color: '#22CC00',
        pointPlacement: -0.5 / 6,
        pointRange: 36e5
    }, {
        name: '3hr span',
        type: 'column',
        data: [{
            "x": 1428073200000,
            "y": 4.9
        }, {
            "x": 1428084000000,
            "y": 4
        }, {
            "x": 1428094800000,
            "y": 3.4
        }, {
            "x": 1428105600000,
            "y": 2.4
        }],
        color: '#22CC00',
        linkedTo: ':previous',
        pointRange: 3 * 36e5,
        pointPlacement: -0.5 / 2
    }, {
        name: '6hr span',
        type: 'column',
        data: [{
            "x": 1428127200000,
            "y": 6.9
        }],
        color: '#22CC00',
        linkedTo: ':previous',
        pointRange: 6 * 36e5,
        pointPlacement: -0.5
    }]
```

Comment: Almost by trial and error, I had come to the same solution -- see http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/215tnLna/19/ -- in this jsfiddle I have included the "working" to show how I calculated `pointPlacement` for each series based on the `pointRange` of this and the higher series.  But it bothered me that there was a massive gap, so I went further and tried to work out a systematic way of eliminating it... is this the best way of doing it -- see use of `min` and `max` in http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/215tnLna/23/.

Comment: But I should add that in my "real world" code, I'm finding that the left-most columns (one or two) are hidden for some reason when using `min` and `max` like above to eliminate the gap.  There is space for the columns, but they are hidden.  But I need to determined whether it's something else in my settings that is hiding them, because in the jsfiddle above no columns are hidden.

Comment: Hard to say where is problem. Maybe old version of Highcharts?

Comment: Hmm, can't yet find a good reason why the left-most columns in my real world code are being hidden (despite there being room).  This happens with version 4.1.4.  But it doesn't happen when I leave the gap alone (i.e. not using `min` and `max`).  But I'm having to do complicated things, since I have a top x axis, and I'm having to put in "dummy" data as a workaround for another issue (see http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/controlling-extent-of-label-t31846/) so it's possible I have to put in another workaround to the workaround.  I'll see if I can replicate in a simple jsfiddle.

Comment: Try to setup demo with both solutions altogether. It is possible that something between is messing up.

Comment: I think maybe the "two x axes" issue is a red herring.  And I have sort of replicated the main issue in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/215tnLna/28/.  In this jsfiddle the left-most two columns don't disappear as they do in my real code, but the behaviour of the shared tooltip is different for those two columns... you can't actually reach them with the tooltip... it sort of "freezes".  Maybe this is what causes them to disappear in my code (in conjunction with some other factor)?  How would you make the tooltip work OK for all bars in this jsfiddle?  Maybe that would fix my problem?

Comment: Here's a slightly simplified version of the jsfiddle that still illustrates the left-most two columns being 'frozen': http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/215tnLna/29/ -- and the following differs from this only in that the `min` and `max` settings are commented out... thereby unfreezing those columns (and the final one for that matter): http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/215tnLna/30/ -- how do I remove the dead space and yet retain the ability to show the tooltip for all columns?

Comment: I've created a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29444424/highcharts-difficulties-with-variable-width-columns) to avoid a lengthy continuation of these comments :-)

Comment: I think this is just wrong behavior in 4.0.4 version, upgrade to 4.1.4 and works better: http://jsfiddle.net/215tnLna/35/ - in 4.1.4 tooltip logic was rewritten and prevents from such bugs with multiple series on the chart.